# How to export connect, Component and function in one place? (just need advice)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

**Problem**: I'm getting this error below. The error means I didn't import or export my modules correctly.

> expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

- I want to import three different types of modules in one place.

  ```
  import {
      DrawerItem,
      DrawerItems,
      ToggleDrawer }         from '../elements/drawer'; <- calling directory.index
  ```
- Here is drawer/index.jsx. So we can import Drawer related components in one place.

  ```
  export * from './drawer_header';
  export * from './drawer_item';
  export * from './drawer_items';
  export * from './drawer';
  export * from './toggle_drawer';
  ```

1) Here is DrawerItem -- Component with `connect`

```
class DrawerItem extends PureComponent {
...
const drawer_component = connect(
    ({ ui }) => ({
        is_portfolio_drawer_on: ui.is_portfolio_drawer_on,
        togglePortfolioDrawer : ui.togglePortfolioDrawer,
    })
)(DrawerItem);

export { drawer_component as DrawerItem };
```

2) Here is DrawerItems - normal component

```
class DrawerItems extends PureComponent {
...
export default { DrawerItems };
```

3) Here is ToggleDrawer - normal component

```
class ToggleDrawer extends React.PureComponent { 
...
export default { ToggleDrawer };
```

**Do you see any problem? What would be the problem?**

Comment: what would happen if you change your `index.jsx` to `index.js`? Just a hunch, but worth a try maybe?

Comment: you cannot use export default in that way

Comment: Try to have a look at my Github repo to see how i export the components and methods and using `index.js` to reexport * again. https://github.com/isaaclem/money-money-home/tree/master/src/actions

Comment: Thanks!!!!! It gives me another error. I need to look into it..

Comment: It's fixed!!!!!! ><><><><<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `default` while exporting in `ToggleDrawer` and `DrawerItems` if you want to import and export them like you did in `drawer/index.jsx`